# Change Folder in Resharper Multi File Template

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

I have my classes dived into several folders like this:
Domain/ModuleName/Models
Domain/ModuleName/Repositories

Now, i want to create an automatic repository when adding a modelclass.
This is done with Resharpers Multi File Template.

But how can i add my Repository (ICustomerRepository.cs) into the Repositories folder?

I can't hardcode a path, because the modulename is variable and i can't find to navigate upwards in my folder (Resharpers tells it has to be a backslash, but it's not working)

[image]